# SSRS Returning 1 Single Figure Differently to the rest of the resultset

Tags: reporting-services

This is a really strange one. I have a dataset which returns a small number of columns and a very small number of rows (49 in my example). I have an SSRS report with a table returning the data from that dataset.

Everything works perfectly, as I would expect........expect one value in one row! It does not return the figure that is in the dataset. Every other figure shows exactly as it is. This occurs in VS and once deployed.

So, in my dataset, the figure shows as -0.955980288917914. In the report, which is formatted to show as a 1 decimal place %, I would expect to see -95.6. It doesn't, it shows -999999900.0%. I have other negative figures in the dataset which show correctly. Its just this one figure. All the other figures show a similar number of decimal places.

I know, I could do the percentage calculation in SQL and just return it to the report but I'm curious as to why this behaviour is happening.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. SQL version is 13.0.5292.0, Visual Studio SSDT is 15.9.16 and Reporting Services is 2016.

Thanks

UPDATE:

Sorry for the delay. Below are some screen snippets.

This is the data as shown in SQL Server, you will see all numbers have similar decimal places.
[image: Raw Data]

This one is from VS and shows the simple design. The highlighted cell is the one holding the % value
[image: Design]

This is the output of that column. As you can see, its only that one figure that is completely wrong. All other 48 figures are correct.
[image: Output]

Thanks again for your help

Comment: A couple of things to check. Click the refresh button on to report toolbar (no the browser refresh) as it could be cached data. Open your dataset set and execute it from within Visual Studio, make sure you see the correct number there. If that all fails, edit your question and show you report design including any grouping you have and all you relevant expressions.

Comment: A couple of other things -- is the report using a regional number formatting that uses a period for a comma?  SSRS could be misinterpreting the value to display.  Could you provide a few more examples of that field?  Are all the values using 15 digits of precision or is this one an outlier?

Comment: Thanks for responding, its been a pretty mad day. I will come back to you tomorrow if that is OK.